# Homebrew: undefined method `min_named'

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

When I was trying to install a package with brew, this error message shows up:

```
Error: undefined method `min_named' for #<Homebrew::CLI::Parser:0x00007ff950288790>
Please report this bug:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:91:in `block in install_args'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cli/parser.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cli/parser.rb:51:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:17:in `new'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:17:in `install_args'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:96:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:103:in `<main>'
```

And when I try to install other packages the same result was shown.

When I run `brew doctor` the result is:`Your system is ready to brew.`

Does anyone know what's wrong with my computer or how to fix this?

Comment: Try to re-install Homebrew.

Comment: Please post the output of `brew config`

Comment: need more debugging output, like `brew config`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem as yours.
And I've solved that by

```
brew update -v
```

Hope that helps you!

我之前是在配置Kafka和Zookeeper的时候出的问题
具体函数名都不一样 但是我看好多都是这个问题
也不知道你有没有解决